# positive/ negative Fluidum

Tags: synonym, latin

Ist das Wort "Fluidum" gebräuchlich? Kann man sagen, dass eine Person positive/negative Fluida verbreitet? (Im Sinne: positive oder negative Wellen schickt)

Comment: Bitte ledit]iere Deine Frage, um klarzustellen: Was bezweckst Du mit der Änderung? Was soll der Beispielsatz bedeuten? Bist Du wirklich an *grammatikalischer* Korrektheit interessiert?

Comment: Was für Wellen? Schallwellen?

Comment: Ich meinte, die Aura,  die positive oder negative Energie.

Comment: Gebräuchlich ist es nicht, aber sagen kann man es schon, und man klingt sogar gebildet dabei.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ich weiß nicht, ob das "gebildet" klingt. Es klingt eher esoterisch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im Deutschen benutzt man als Bild Lichtstrahlen, wobei es auch »Dunkelstrahlen« gibt.

> Sie hat eine positive/negative **Ausstrahlung**.
>
> Sie **strahlt** viel Frohsinn/Neid **aus**.

Oder du benutzt das Fremdwort **Aura**.

> Eine **Aura** des Positiven/Negativen umgab ihn.

Answer (score 3):

Fluidum ist im Duden ([Link](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Fluidum)), insofern kann man es offiziell wohl benutzen.

Aber aufgepasst. Das Wort ist sehr ungebräuchlich. Laut Google ngram ([Link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Fluidum&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CFluidum%3B%2Cc0)) wird Fluidum seit dem 19. Jahrhundert immer weniger benutzt. Ich als Muttersprachler habe es noch nie im Sprachgebrauch angetroffen.

Comment: Höchste Zeit, dass es mehr benützt wird. Stoßen wir drauf an! Erheben wir die Gläser voll des goldnen Fluidums!

Answer (score 2):

Das [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Fluidum) hat einen Eintrag zu `Fluidum`, dessen Etymologie hier hilft.

Zu einer Zeit, wo die Physik noch nicht genug über Aggregatszustände der Materie, Energien, Kräfte und Wirkungen wusste, hat man den Begriff benutzt, um Wirkungen zu beschreiben, die keines Vorhandenseins fester Körper benötigen, sondern stattdessen nur eines Fluides (also Flüssigkeit oder Gas), oder die selbst ein Fluid sind.

Heutzutage trennt man sauber zwischen diesen Begriffen und weiß, dass Kontakt -- egal ob durch fest oder fluide Körper -- überhaupt keine allgemeine Bedingung für Kräfte ist. Der Begriff hat sich damit in den Naturwissenschaften erübrigt.

In den Geisteswissenschaften und Künsten scheint er aber dennoch ab und zu einmal zu fallen, wobei ich persönlich das Gefühl habe, dass er entweder durch die falsche Benutzung der naturwissenschaftlichen Begriffe Energie, Schwingung, Welle oder durch die Benutzung esoterischer Begriffe wie Aura immer mehr ersetzt wird.

Answer (score 0):

Es wurden schon kluge Dinge geäußert zum Wort Fluidum, aber auf die eigentliche Frage ging noch keiner pünktlich ein:

> Ist das Wort "Fluidum" gebräuchlich? Kann man sagen, dass eine Person positive/negative Fluida verbreitet? (Im Sinne: positive oder negative Wellen schickt)

Antwort:

Gebräuchlich ist das Wort nicht. Benützen kann man es trotzdem, und man klingt sogar gebildet dabei.

Jedoch finde ich es falsch verwendt in einem Satz wie "eine Person verbreitet [irgendwelche] Fluida". Nach meinem Verständnis ist ein Fluidum etwas, - vorgestellt in der Art einer Flüssigkeit oder eines Gases, wenn auch weniger physisch als geistig - das nicht räumlich beschränkt gedacht wird. So etwa wie die Luft. Diese ist auch überall [bezogen auf den Raum menschlichen Alltagserlebens natürlich], und in ihr können sich z.B. Wellen ausbreiten, aber die Luft selbst breitet sich nicht aus. Verwandt vom Konzept her oft: der Äther. Ähnlich würde ich  mir ein Fluidum denken. Es ist halt da, aber verbreiten kann man es nicht.

Aber natürlich kann man Wörter so und so verwenden. Wer sich einen Scherz machen will, kann jegliche Flüssigkeit, und sei es das Bier im Glas, ein Fluidum nennen und ihm heftig zusprechen.